# VS-2019 16.3.3 changes code page of RC files when saving

Tags: utf-8, mfc, visual-studio-2019, rc

I am using VS-2019 and just updated to 16.3.3.

Now the resource editor changes the encoding of my RC files from codepage 1252 to UTF-8.
The problem is, that I have tools that need to touch and translate the RC files. This tools can't handle UTF-8 encoded files.

Is there a way to prevent that VS-2019 changes the encoding of the file?

I already filed a [problem for this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/771209/saveing-a-rc-file-in-the-new-vs-2019-converts-the.html).

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/756433/converting-resource-files-rc-to-utf8-in-mfc-projec.html

Comment: Yes found the first issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/757607/automatic-ansi-rc-file-conversion-to-utf8-not-want.html

Comment: Is this still an issue ? I'm using VS 16.11.8 and my resources get converted, so I can't use the resource editor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed in the new Update for VS-2019 Version, see link here [16.3.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.3.6)